# Can we convert PDF into image using flutter in order to show thumbnail of the file?

Tags: html, image, pdf, flutter, dart

**Use-Case: In order to show thumbnail of the PDF in file list.**

**Question 2:** Can we convert FPF to image to show thumbnail in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Correct Answer:** Using [Printing](https://pub.dev/packages/printing) and [pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) plugin, In order to convert PDF to image we can simply achieve this by:

```
// send pdfFile as params
imageFromPdfFile(File pdfFile) async {
    final document = await lib.PDFDocument.openFile(pdfFile.path);
    final page = await document.getPage(1);
    final pageImage = await page.render(width: page.width, height: page.height);
    await page.close();
    print(pageImage.bytes);

    //... now convert 
    // .... pageImage.bytes to image
}
```

Comment: i guss you refer wrong plugin because pdf plugin not contain PDFDocument method   lib.PDFDocument.openFile(pdfFile.path);  it is only for creating pdf  you can use pdf_render instead..

Comment: lib.PDFDocument.openFile(pdfFile.path); df plugin not contain PDFDocument

Comment: think you are refering to another plugin like @akshayyadav told you bedore the pdf plugin doesn't have any PDFDocument class.

Comment: PDFDocument class updated to Document class. Please go through the plugin docs.

Comment: none of the provided methods exist ?!, please update

Answer (score 3):

Using [pdf_render](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf_render) and [image](https://pub.dev/packages/image) plugins.

```
import 'package:pdf_render/pdf_render.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as imglib;


final doc = await PdfDocument.openFile('abc.pdf');
final pages = doc.pageCount;
List<imglib.Image> images = [];

// get images from all the pages
for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++) {
  var page = await doc.getPage(i);
  var imgPDF = await page.render();
  var img = await imgPDF.createImageDetached();
  var imgBytes = await img.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);
  var libImage = imglib.decodeImage(imgBytes.buffer
      .asUint8List(imgBytes.offsetInBytes, imgBytes.lengthInBytes));
  images.add(libImage);
}

// stitch images
int totalHeight = 0;
images.forEach((e) {
  totalHeight += e.height;
});
int totalWidth = 0;
images.forEach((element) {
  totalWidth = totalWidth < element.width ? element.width : totalWidth;
});
final mergedImage = imglib.Image(totalWidth, totalHeight);
int mergedHeight = 0;
images.forEach((element) {
  imglib.copyInto(mergedImage, element, dstX: 0, dstY: mergedHeight, blend: false);
  mergedHeight += element.height;
});

// Save image as a file
final documentDirectory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
File imgFile = new File('${documentDirectory.path}/abc.jpg');
new File(imgFile.path).writeAsBytes(imglib.encodeJpg(mergedImage));
```

Answer (score 1):

[I built a package](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf_thumbnail), which is simply a widget that shows thumbnails of PDF.

[image]

The way of I'm getting each page is via [pdfx](https://pub.dev/packages/pdfx) package.

Here's the line of code from my package.

https://github.com/mirkancal/pdf_thumbnail/blob/main/lib/src/pdf_thumbnail.dart#L77

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could achieve this is by using [pdfx](https://pub.dev/packages/pdfx). (install this package)

### **First, you should get the image from your pdf file:**

```
  Future<PdfPageImage?> getImage() async {
    final document = await PdfDocument.openAsset('assets/cv.pdf');

    final page = await document.getPage(1);

    final image = await page.render(
      width: page.width * 2, //decrement for less quality
      height: page.height * 2,
      format: PdfPageImageFormat.jpeg,
      backgroundColor: '#ffffff',

      // Crop rect in image for render
      //cropRect: Rect.fromLTRB(left, top, right, bottom),
    );

    return image;
  }
```

feel free to use a pdf from your assets of from a file.

### **We can then show the created image in our widget:**

```
FutureBuilder(
   future: getImage(), //<- created image
   builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<PdfPageImage?> snapshot) {

   // data is ready
   if(snapshot.hasData) {

       PdfPageImage image = snapshot.data!;
       return Image.memory(image.bytes);

    // loading
    } else {
       return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
    }

  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Printing](https://pub.dev/packages/printing), you simply pass in the bytes from any PDF document.

```dart
/// Load a local PDF file
Future<Uint8List> loadPdf(File pdfFile) async {
  Future<Uint8List> documentBytes = pdfFile.readAsBytes();
  return documentBytes;
}

/// Pass in document bytes to render image using [Printing]
/// pages: [0] set to 0 to render first page only.
getImageFromPdf(Future<Uint8List> documentBytes) async {
  await for (var page in pw.Printing.raster(await documentBytes, pages: [0], dpi: 72)) {
    final image = page.toImage(); // ...or page.toPng()
    print(image);
  }
}
```

You can load the PDF document bytes using any method, e.g.

- Load from local storage as a File `import 'dart:io';` and use the `.readAsBytes()` method.
- Use a package like [pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) to create/edit a PDF then pass the bytes.
- Download via http, etc.